# Eigenvectors are unique up to a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $ A $ is a matrix with eigenvector $ v $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $ \lambda, $ can we prove that $ v $ is unique up to $ \lambda, $ that is if $ v $ and $ v' $ are eigenvectors corresponding to $ \lambda, $ then $ v = Cv' $ for some constant $ C. $

Comment: No, consider the identity matrix.

Comment: Look for example at the all zeros matrix. Everything is an eigenvector. If there are $n$ **distinct** eigenvalues, where the matrix is $n\times n$, then the (essential) uniqueness holds, but not necessarily otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

No. It is quite possible for an eigenspace to have more than one dimension. As commenters above pointed out, examples include the identity matrix or the zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have repeated eigenvalues, you won't have a unique eigenvector, but eigenspace that includes infinite number of vectors. BUT if your eigenvalue unique, then you have one eigenvector corresponding to it which up to a constant, by which u multiply this vector, i.e. [1 1] and [2 2] is the same.